# Facebook share not working in android for accounts other than developer account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think this is one of the question in which i am getting confused and not getting clear picture even after reading the documentation of facebook.

My question is

- I have created one developer account and one normal facebook account.
- Now in mine application i want that the user should be able to log in and share the things
- With Developers account i am able to login and share the things also but with the other account which is not a developers account i am able to successfully logged in but not able to share the things on the wall.

I have read the documentation and there it's mentioning that the app need to be submitted for approval.

Hence my point is I am confused with this part do i really need to submit the application for approval or it can be done without approval also.

For the share part I have used the Facebook sample example (publishFeedHowTo). The github link is :

> https://github.com/fbsamples/android-3.0-howtos/tree/master/PublishFeedHowTo/src/com/facebook/samples/publishfeedhowto

Answer (score 1):

Your app must have to be reviewed by the fb developers for this.

Comment: Ok.. so do i need to submit my apk which is still in development phase

Comment: Yes, they will take 2-3 business days to review your app. And do follow their guidelines.

Comment: If you still develop it, it doesn't make any sense to submit it to review.

Answer (score 1):

Nope there's no way other than getting approval from Facebook.

I myself have sought approval for a few apps of mine, facebook generally takes 2-3 business days to review your app and allow you to share from other accounts